# JS/CSS Framework for Control Panel-like web application

Tags: javascript, css, controls, javascript-framework, css-frameworks

So I'm currently working on a web app that I'm just going to use on my network to manage a few things like a file server and the sorts. Does anyone know of a JS/CSS Framework that I can use for the UI. I've used jQuery a lot but it doesn't exactly fit the bill for what I need. I also would like to code it myself but if anyone knows of any applications for this purpose thats easily expandable, that would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

It has rich UI widgets, cross browser compatible, extensible and has clean component model.

Comment: I've decided to go with ExtJS. I've never tried it but it looks great (especially the Web Desktop demo. Basically what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1):

Since you say *"I've used jQuery a lot"* and *"I also would like to code it myself"* i suggest jQuery and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).  Also to be honest, it seems like you're going to need to be doing some back-end coding too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that a little clearer: I have used jQuery UI before and, don't get me wrong, its a great JS Framework but it just doesnt fit the bill.

Comment: P.S. Im probably better at back-end coding than I am at front-end

Answer (score 0):

Any of them will work. jQuery + jQuery UI seems like an obvious choice. Anything in particular you don't like about it?

Other than that, ExtJS is quite popular too.

Nearly any of the JS frameworks will work, though. We'd need more specifics to help narrow it down for you.

As for CSS frameworks, things like jQuery UI and ExtJS come with their own CSS to go with their components.

For something independent of the JS, I'd look at BluePrint.css and 960.css